# SwiftUI Chart annotation issue when introducing background color

Tags: swift, swiftui, charts, annotations

I have the following straightforward code for a swiftUI chart:

```
ForEach(displayPoints, id:\.point.dryBulb.value.value.self) { displayPT in
            PointMark(
                x: .value("", displayPT.point.getCGpoint().x),
                y: .value("", displayPT.point.getCGpoint().y)
            )
            .foregroundStyle(Color.secondaryCyan500)
            .symbolSize(70.0)
            .annotation(position: .topLeading, alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                Text(displayPT.abbreviation)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 12)).bold()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.secondaryCyan500)
            }
```

At this stage, everything works perfectly, and the annotations display correctly without any problem.

However, since these annotations are hard to read on the chart, I introduced a harmless `.background(Color.white)` modifier to the Text view inside `.annotation()` as follows:

```
.annotation(position: .topLeading, alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
       Text(displayPT.abbreviation)
           .font(Font.system(size: 12)).bold()
           .foregroundColor(Color.secondaryCyan500)
           .background(Color.white) // <---- this
 }
```

The result now is that the value string of the annotations are not longer correct. In many cases, the same annotation string is displayed over multiple points, even though they are labeled differently.

Any idea what kid of framework bug could be causing this issue, and is there a way around it? Keeping the annotations without background color is just bad UI design.

PS. I tried nesting the Text view inside an Hstack and apply the background to the Hstack instead, but the result is the same.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of the data you used? I tried it with 5 points on the x=y line, and I cannot reproduce.

Comment: Hi @Sweeper , thank you for answering. The chart has many components and I don't think there's a way to include all of the potentially problematic parts while keeping the question of a reasonable length. But you just gave me an idea to start by taking out some parts that will not break the code and see if I can find something. Thanks again.